# Copying pivottable results with multiple columns

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I have a workbook that has a data connection and I set up a pivot table as seen below:

[image]

The pivottable results are based on:

[image]

I am trying to copy, transfer, whatever those results by column (day) then (Good QTY) and move them to another sheet so they look like below:

[image]

I have been trying different things for hours with no results. I have tried recording macros, `.Copy Destination`, Select then copy, `Getpivotdata` and nothing is working. The only thing I can get working is selecting 1 "Good Qty" from 1 Line.

The closest thing I got to work was the following code:

`Sheets("Pivot_Table").PivotTables("Metric_Display").PivotSelect("Good Qty")`

this selects each column by day and all the "Good Qty" but I can not copy because I get the error saying I cant copy multiple sections.

This workbook updates daily and adds a new Day column as a result, the next thing I was try was just a find last column used and copy and paste the cells them selfs instead of using the pivot table but I figured there has to be a way to use the table.
Any suggestions would be much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a week of searching I found the a solution.

```
Set PvtTbl = Workbooks("AX_Cube_Report").Sheets("Good_Qty_Data").PivotTables("Good_Qty_PT")
PvtTbl.TableRange2.Offset(4, 0).Copy
Workbooks("AX_Cube_Report").Sheets("Good_Qty").Cells(2, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

The Key is the `.TableRange2` command

I then count the rows and columns to delete the unwanted rows.